# All possible co-prime computation efficiently

Tags: math, primes, prime-factoring

I need a function which will give me `is_coprime(m, n)` in constant time. In my case, `1 < m, n < 100`. So I can easily pre-compute the values and store them in an 100x100 array.

My approach would be to store `gcd(m,n) == 1` for each m,n index in the array. However this is also time-consuming. So I was wondering if there is a well-known algorithmic solution for this type of problems, where all possible gcd / co-prime over a 1 to N range is needed.

Comment: `m == n` would fill the diagonal with mostly false (1 being the exception). `m < n` would hold for (n, m) too. The real intelligence can only come from using (m, i), (n, j), (i, j) intelligently, to eliminate calling gcd: not is_coprime(13, m) and not is_coprime(13, n) implies not is_coprime(m, n). The sieve of Eratosthenes might be considered.

Comment: If performance is important enough that the one off cost of computing the table is a problem, you could write a separate program to compute the table and write a source file that your real program can include.

Comment: Also, there are only 98 integers > 1 and < 100.

Comment: *My approach would be to store gcd(m,n) == 1 for each m,n index in the array. However this is also time-consuming.* For 10,000 entries? On my computer that took less than 2 milliseconds. What's your definition of time-consuming?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk You are correct. After using the C++ standard library gcd, I am also getting extremely low times.